# Best storage for a high numbers rows?

Tags: mysql

This is my case.

There are nearly 240 categories and each category has at least 10 subcategories.

I think the best storage for these +20 million rows is to do it in partitions (category field) and sub-partitions (year field).

Can you please give me an idea of how to create the table?

Thank you in advance

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `folders`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `folders` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT',
  `number` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `category` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `year` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `subfolder` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC COMMENT='index folders';
```

Comment: I would read up on partitioning. Partitioning by year is discouraged, but a similar approach is suggested instead.

Comment: what it's your suggest please? now, all my rows it's stored by year and category but it's verry low to run select

Comment: if y use only partition (one level - without subpartition) in the next future i have more that 1M rows